# sufficient statistics and isometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, st.statistics

Let $(M,g)$ be an infinite dimensional statistical manifold with the Fisher information metric $g$. Is it true that any isometry on this manifold must correspond to a sufficient statistic?

Comment: I don't know an answer, but I wonder if you have a few concrete examples?

Comment: I'm thinking of the manifold $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  It's the upper half-plane, with metric something like $\displaystyle\sqrt{d\mu^2+\frac{d\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}}$?  The minimal sufficient statistic for an i.i.d. sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is just the pair $(X_1+\cdots+X_n,X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)$.  How would this correspond to some isometry?